# How to make wordpress CSS modifications visible to all browsers that have old versions stored in their cache?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have a wordpress website but whenever i make a css mod, that is not visible to all other browsers. The browsers show old versions of that css file. this modifications are visibles only if i manually delete the old chache stored in the browesers.
how can i force the "world wide" browsers to look for a new versions of that css since a changing occurred?

i have this string in the function.php

```
wp_enqueue_style('my-theme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/style.css'), false);
```

thank you

Comment: You can via applying version to your `wp_enqueue_style` but I can see that you are already doing that with `filemtime()` so my next guess will be to check if modification date actually change when you make modification in this css file. Side question: do you have any cache plugin installed?

Comment: my host is SiteGround that has is own caching plug-in SGOptimizer Dynamic & Memecad. In Fact inspecting with the console i don't see the style.css but this: ...siteground-optimizer-assets/siteground-optimizer-combined-css-c2ceb412ea0e3e5177

Comment: In this plugin options look for option like "combine css". Try to disable it for now and don't forget to enable it after you will complete development.

Comment: ok if i understand, i have to disable combine whenever i make some edit on style.css and then rigenerate the new cobined version ectivating again that specific function on the plug in when i finish. Thank you a lot i will try.

Comment: Is this page on production or in development? If it is in development then you don't have to enable "combine css" yet. Enable it when you move this site on production and open to public.

Comment: No No the websitw is open to the public. I constantly do some mod the the css to change the style. So i need changes to be visible as soon as possible to anyone hooked to my website. Anyway it seems that disabling combine and then enabling it again the changes are visible. Thank you!